# How to delete the 2nd to last element from a list in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I'm using Scheme and I'm trying to remove the 2nd to last element in the list recursively.
This is what I have:

```
(define delete
  (lambda (num lst)
    (cond 
      ((equal? (length lst) 1) '())
      ((null? lst) '())
      (else (cons (car lst)(delete num (cdr lst)))))))

(define second
  (lambda(lst)
    (delete (- (length lst) 1) lst)))

(second '(1))
(second '(3 5 6))
(second '(2 7 8 4 9))
```

returns this:

```
()
(3 5)
(2 7 8 4)
```

When it should return this:

```
()
(3 6)
(2 7 8 9)
```

The (second '(1)) is doing what I intended but I've playing with the other part for a few hours and I'm still at a loss. Any tips or suggestions would be very appreciated at this point.

EDIT:
Wow, Thank you! It was that one line of missing code -_- Duh me!

Comment: Was the answer below a good one? Consider clicking the check mark to give the responder credit for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use the num argument. So you will always iterate until the list has 1 element or is null. You could add a special case for when the list has 2 elements:

```
(define delete
  (lambda (num lst)
    (cond 
      ((equal? (length lst) 2) (cdr lst))
      ((equal? (length lst) 1) '())
      ((null? lst) '())
      (else (cons (car lst)(delete num (cdr lst)))))))

(define second
  (lambda(lst)
    (delete (- (length lst) 1) lst)))
```

Since the num argument isn't used, you can do:

```
(define delete_second_last
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond 
      ((equal? (length lst) 2) (cdr lst))
      ((equal? (length lst) 1) '())
      ((null? lst) '())
      (else (cons (car lst)(delete_second_last (cdr lst)))))))

(delete_second_last '(3 6 7 9 10))
```